# LINQ Convert var collection to a specific collection type

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have this code:

```
public class ExistedProducts
 {
    public int productID{get;set;}
    public int productQte{get;set;}
 }
```

..
..
..

```
public List<ExistedProducts> GetStock()
{
   var result = from p in Products 
   join st in Stock on st.ProductID equals p.ID
   select new{ExistedProductID=p.ID,ExistedProductQte = st.Qte};
   return result.Cast<ExistedProducts>.ToList();// exception here 
}
```

My first question, can I directly produce the typed collection from the query?
If not, how can I do the casting (i called the Cast() method but a raised exception saying impossible to do cast from

> '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int32,System.Int32] ?

I want to avoid the copy by loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes instead of projecting `anonymous type` you can directly project your type `ExistedProducts` like this:-

```
var result = (from p in Products 
             join st in Stock on st.ProductID equals p.ID
             select new ExistedProducts
                         {
                              productID = p.ID,
                              productQte = st.Qte
                         }).ToList();
return result;
```